# get USER ID in functions.php using user_register action

Tags: functions, users, id

I am having trouble of getting the ID in user_register filter in functions.php...

Here is what I got

```
add_action( 'user_register', 'sendanotheremail' );
function sendanotheremail($user_id) {
        $user = new WP_User($user_id);
        $user_login = stripslashes($user->user_login);
        $user_email = stripslashes($user->user_email);
        $getid      = $user->ID;
        global $wpdb;
        $getunion = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT value from wp_bp_xprofile_data where user_id = $getid AND field_id = 4", "ARRAY_N");
        $message  = sprintf(__('New user registration on %s:'), get_option('blogname')) . "\r\n\r\n";
        $message .= sprintf(__('Username: %s'), $user_login) . "\r\n\r\n";
        $message .= sprintf(__('E-mail: %s'), $user_email) . "\r\n";
        $message .= "<br /> Please go here to approve the new user <a href=\"http://xxx.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=bp_registration_options_member_requests\">Approve/Deny</a>";
        if(!($getunion)) {
                $message .= "nothing there";
        }
        else {
                $message .= "yes";
        }
$headers = 'From: xxx <xxx@xxx.com>';
add_filter('wp_mail_content_type',create_function('', 'return "text/html";'));
wp_mail('xxx@xxx.com', 'New User Registration to xxx website', $message, $headers);
}
```

I am testing the getunion if its empty I am returning "nothing there".

***So all of the other variables are getting me email with right data, but $getunion is empty...***

When I pass manually the ID here

```
$getunion = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT value from wp_bp_xprofile_data where user_id = $get_id AND field_id = 4", "ARRAY_N");
```

it works... So how can I get the ID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are giving `$wpdb->get_results` a string for its second parameter. It should be a constant-- `ARRAY_N`-- meaning you need to remove the quotes

```
$getunion = $wpdb->get_results(
  "SELECT value from wp_bp_xprofile_data where user_id = $getid AND field_id = 4", 
  ARRAY_N
);
```

Since you claim it works in the second instance, I am assuming `$wpdb` compensates, but I haven't verified that. Thought I'd mention it.

I think your problem is here:

```
    $user = new WP_User($user_id);
    $user_login = stripslashes($user->user_login);
    $user_email = stripslashes($user->user_email);
    $getid      = $user->ID;
```

You have your user ID coming into the function as `$user_id`. I don't know why you are creating another user. I believe that replacing those four lines with the following with sort things out.

```
    $user = get_user_by('id',$user_id);
    $user_login = stripslashes($user->user_login);
    $user_email = stripslashes($user->user_email);
    // $getid      = $user->ID; // you already have the user ID -> $user_id; use that below or change this line to
    $getid = $user_id; // if you must
```

Answer (score 0):

From the doc:

> This hook allows you to access data for a new user **immediately after**
>   they are added to the database. User id is passed to hooked functions
>   as an argument.

You already have the newly-created user ID passed into the function as `$user_id`. What you're doing is you're calling `new WP_User()` with an already existing ID, so that's probably going to fail every time.

Comment: `new WP_User($user_id)` creates a new object instance of the [`WP_User`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User) class. It *should* be passed an existing ID...